# Shell batch script for loop to access different lists of variables

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to use a `for` loop in a batch script to change some variables in a file.

I can do that successfully with one variable, as the `for` loop runs through the list associated with that variable. Now I need the second variable to run at the same time and replace the value in the file. Here is the code I am using:

```
#!bin/bash

declare -a subjectID=(AA BB CC)

for subject in ${subjectID[@]}
do

sed -i 's/XX/'$subject'/g' design.txt

done
```

Now I want a 2nd variable (say, named `volume`) with a different list of values, but still the same process of using `sed` to replace some characters in the txt file.

Any help?

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to do the same loop with the 2nd variable (volume) in parallel with loop you have already written the first variable, replacing the same string with different values?

Comment: use double quote around your sed if you use variable inside avoiding to play with open/close simple quote

Comment: @PhilipAdler, not the same string, a different one, but the loop needs to run in paralell. I have the same number of elements in the list 'SubjectID' and 'Volumes' and want the variables to be replaced in parallel

Comment: Thankyou for the clarification, forgive me if I am being dense, but *why* do you want the loops running in parallel?

Comment: @PhilipAdler the txt file has two variables that need to change at the same time, since this txt file is needed to run a script at each iteration of the loop (there are lines missing in the code that show the script being called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should meet your needs:

```
#!bin/bash

declare -a subjectID=(AA BB CC);
declare -a volume=(xx yy zz);

i=0;

while [ $i -lt ${#subjectID[@]} ] #assumes you can guarantee the array lengths are the same
do

    sed -i '' 's/XX/'${subjectID[$i]}'/g' design.txt;
    sed -i '' 's/YY/'${volume[$i]}'/g' design.txt;

    #call your other thing here
    let i=$i+1;
done
```

Comment: I tried this, but now I get an error saying 'invalid command name "i"', could this be because I need to declare i first? (sorry, I'am a newbie in shell scripting)

Comment: An invalid command name like that is normally caused if you mistype `i=0` as `i = 0`; in bash, these are two different things.

Comment: That is not the problem since I kept it exactly like you wrote (just changed the "subject" to "subjectID" in sed). How is i being incremented? Is this within the while loop declaration?

Comment: Oops! Yes, that is the idea!

Comment: Edited the code; I missed a couple of $ signs as well (this is what I get for answering an SO question about bash while being knee deep in C/C++ !)

Comment: Thanks, but this is still not working, it keeps saying "i" is an invalid command name invoked from within the other thing I am running. The code you gave me is not replacing "XX" with the elements of the list! (Also, i=i+1 did not work but i+=1 seems to do the trick!)

Comment: What is the other thing you are running- I can't comment on what that is doing.

I corrected `i=i+1` to `i=$i+1`. Sorry for the stupid little mistakes.

Comment: The invocation of sed we have been using is wrong, and is a little platform dependent. Corrected my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54283/discussion-between-philip-adler-and-pl-rl).

Comment: I'm sorry, the other thing I am running is "feat" from the "fsl" package (from fMRI analysis). Now it just says "integer expression expected" in the while loop line. Thanks again for all the help